# How to calculate the Beta index of a graph from its adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

A ratio of the number edges to the number of vertices of a graph $G$ is called Beta index of $G$; it is denoted by $\beta$. In the following figure, the number of edges and the number of vertices are $2$ and $3$, respectively. Therefore, $\beta=\frac{2}{3}$.

[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRDXL.jpg)

Also, the adjacency matrix of the above graph is

$$
   A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} .
$$
Suppose, by presuming the fact that every adjacency matrix corresponds to an undirected graph, how can we calculate the beta index of a graph by simply observing its adjacency matrix without looking at the graph? For a moment, i thought that the Beta index as the ratio of the number of non-zero entries to the total entries of the adjacency matrix (but it proved to be wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ones in the adjacency matrix is the sum of degrees of the vertices which will be twice the number of edges. Hence number of edges is $\frac{\text{no of $1$s in adjacency matrix}}{2}$,  and number of vertices is the number of rows or columns of the adjacency matrix